# Unexpected behaviour when removing inline comments in C

Tags: c, comments, c-preprocessor

Stack Overflow! I am on my learning process with the C technology. I have a function which gets an input file, seeks through the file and writes the contents  to the output file without the comments.
The function works but it also brakes at some cases.
My Function:

```
    void removeComments(char* input, char* output)
{
    FILE* in = fopen(input,"r");
    FILE* out = fopen(ouput,"w");
    char c;
    while((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF)
    {
       if(c == '/')
       {

          c = fgetc(in);
          if(c == '/')
          {
           while((c = fgetc(in)) != '\n');
          }
          else
          {
            fputc('/', out);
          }
       }
       else
       {
           fputc(c,out);
       }
    }
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
}
```

But when I give a file like this as input:

```
// Parameters: a, the first integer; b the second integer.
// Returns: the sum.
int add(int a, int b) 
{
    return a + b; // An inline comment.
}
int sample = sample;
```

When removing the inline comment it fails to reach the '\n' for some reason and it gives output:

```
int add(int a, int b) 
{
    return a + b; }
int sample = sample;
```

[EDIT] 
Thanks for helping me! It works with the case I posted but it brakes in another.
Current code:

```
FILE* in = fopen(input,"r");
FILE* out = fopen(output,"w");

if (in == NULL) {
  printf("cannot read %s\n", input);
  return; /* change signature to return 0 ? */
}
if (out == NULL) {
  printf("cannot write in %s\n", output);
  return; /* change signature to return 0 ? */
}

int c;
int startline = 1;

while((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF)
{
   if(c == '/')
   {
      c = fgetc(in);

      if(c == '/')
      {
        while((c = fgetc(in)) != '\n')
        {
          if (c == EOF) {
            fclose(in);
            fclose(out);
            return; /* change signature to return 1 ? */
          }
        }
        if (! startline)
          fputc('\n', out);
        startline = 1;
      }
      else if (c == EOF)
        break;
      else {
        fputc('/', out);
        startline = 0;
      }
   }
   else
   {
     fputc(c,out);
     startline = (c == '\n');
   }
}

fclose(in);
fclose(out);
```

When the file contains division the second variable disappears.
Example:

```
int divide(int a, int b) 
    {
        return a/b; 
    }
```

It gives back:

```
int divide(int a, int b) 
    {
        return a/; 
    }
```

Comment: you have several problems in your code, look at my answer if you want

Comment: In addition to Bruno's comments, think about what happens if the sequence "`//`" appears in a string literal (where it's not a comment)

Comment: @DavidC. yes, I was thinking about too ;-)

Comment: Note that your code will damage `puts("This // does not mark the start of an inline comment");` — once you've got the basics working, you may need to worry about strings (and even multi-character character literals: `int c = '//XY';` is valid C with implementation-defined results — though such literals are vanishingly rare in real C code).

Comment: Two other nasties for you: ```// this comment continues \``` (with the backslash immediately before a newline) means that the one line comment continues onto at least the next line.  The similar structure at the start of a comment — a string containing `"/\\\n/ This is a comment\n"` where there is a backslash-newline sequence (or multiple BSNL sequences) between the first and second slashes also marks the start of a comment.  Granted, the programmer who writes such code should be shot, hung, drawn and quartered, but some programs need to be bullet-proof. Your call on whether to worry about it.

Comment: You are right for a/b => a/, I edited my code to solve that bug

Comment: There was an other problem, if simple '/' terminate the file it was removed, also corrected in my answer

Comment: @bruno Thank you. Thanks to all of you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after

```
while((c = fgetc(in)) != '\n');
```

you need a `fputc('\n', out);`

Additional remarks :

In

```
char c;
while((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF)
```

*c* must be an *int* to manage EOF

Just a typo : *ouput* must be *output* to compile

You do not manages well the EOF after you read a '/'

You missed to check the result of the *fopen*

---

A proposal :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void removeComments(char* input, char* output)
{
    FILE* in = fopen(input,"r");
    FILE* out = fopen(output,"w");

    if (in == NULL) {
      printf("cannot read %s\n", input);
      return; /* change signature to return 0 ? */
    }
    if (out == NULL) {
      printf("cannot write in %s\n", output);
      return; /* change signature to return 0 ? */
    }

    int c;

    while((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF)
    {
       if(c == '/')
       {
          c = fgetc(in);

          if(c == '/')
          {
            while((c = fgetc(in)) != '\n')
            {
              if (c == EOF) {
                fclose(in);
                fclose(out);
                return; /* change signature to return 1 ? */
              }
            }
            fputc('\n', out);
          }
          else if (c == EOF) {
            fputc('/', out);
            break;
          }
          else
            fputc('/', out);
            fputc(c, out);
       }
       else
       {
         fputc(c,out);
       }
    }

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
     /* change signature to return 1 ? */
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  removeComments(argv[1], argv[2]);
}
```

---

As Tormund Giantsbane says in a remark it is better to completely remove the line containing only a comment (comment starting on the first column), that new proposal does that :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void removeComments(char* input, char* output)
{
    FILE* in = fopen(input,"r");
    FILE* out = fopen(output,"w");

    if (in == NULL) {
      printf("cannot read %s\n", input);
      return; /* change signature to return 0 ? */
    }
    if (out == NULL) {
      printf("cannot write in %s\n", output);
      return; /* change signature to return 0 ? */
    }

    int c;
    int startline = 1;

    while((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF)
    {
       if(c == '/')
       {
          c = fgetc(in);

          if(c == '/')
          {
            while((c = fgetc(in)) != '\n')
            {
              if (c == EOF) {
                fclose(in);
                fclose(out);
                return; /* change signature to return 1 ? */
              }
            }
            if (! startline)
              fputc('\n', out);
            startline = 1;
          }
          else if (c == EOF) {
            fputc('/', out);
            break;
          }
          else {
            fputc('/', out);
            fputc(c, out);
            startline = 0;
          }
       }
       else
       {
         fputc(c,out);
         startline = (c == '\n');
       }
    }

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
     /* change signature to return 1 ? */
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  removeComments(argv[1], argv[2]);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -g r.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat i
// Parameters: a, the first integer; b the second integer.
// Returns: the sum.
int add(int a, int b) 
{
    return a + b/c; // An inline comment.
}
int sample = sample;
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out i o
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat o
int add(int a, int b) 
{
    return a + b/c; 
}
int sample = sample;
```

---

As said by DavidC. in a remark if // is placed in a string the result will not be the expected one, it is also the case in a character even illegal (I mean '//' must not be changed), what about the C comments (/* .. // ... */) etc

Answer (score 2):

> When removing the inline comment it fails to reach the '\n' for some reason

Well no, if it failed to reach or see the newline at the end of an inline comment then the program would, presumably, consume the entire rest of the file.  What it actually fails to do is *write* such newlines to the output.

Consider your comment-eating code:

> ```
>            while((c = fgetc(in)) != '\n');
> ```

That loop terminates when a newline is read.  At that point, the newline, having already been read, is not available to be read from the input again, so your general read / write provisions will not handle it.  If you want the such newlines to be preserved, then you need to print them in the comment-handling branch.

Additional notes:

1. `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`, and you need to handle it as such in order to be able to correctly detect end-of-file.
2. Your program will go into an infinite loop if the input ends with an inline comment that is not terminated by a newline.  Such source is technically non-conforming, but even so, you ought to handle it.